# In Solaris how do you start App Builder CDE?

Tags: solaris, oracle-linux

I have a Oracle Solaris 11 installed on a VM. I am trying to start the App. Builder program by dtbuilder as mentioned in the documentation but unable to start. I cannot find /usr/dt directory either. Does anyone has a similar problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You must be looking at documentation for the wrong version of Solaris.  CDE, including the app builder, is not included in Solaris 11 and later.  Solaris 10 was the last version to include it - it was obsoleted and replaced by the GNOME desktop instead.

Answer (score 0):

Although Solaris 11 does not include CDE, [it was open sourced under the LGPLv2 in 2012](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/08/09/cde_goes_opensource/), so in principle it's still possible to use it if you build it from source.  [The source is available on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cdesktopenv/).